# IOS how to compare two array with different values and number of elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, if-statement

I have two array, array A has 4 elements and array B has 10 elements. How to compare this two array together to find out whether array A has values that contains in array B.

Here is the codes.

```
   for(int i = 0; i <= deepsightSig.count; i++){
    for(int p = 0; p <= feeds.count; i++){


        if(feeds[i] == deepsightSig[i]){

            badIPCount++;


        }
        else
            goodIPCount++;

    }


}
```

Comment: You just need to check arrayB contain object from Array A

Comment: Do the arrays contain the same type of objects?  Would equivalent objects compare as equal when sent the `isEqual:` message?

Comment: Array A and Array B contains same types of objects but different number of elements. for example array A has 4 elements but array B has 10 elements.

Comment: Please show me the updated codes i listed. Thank You

Comment: I post answer with two array.So Please Check it

Comment: Look, your code is absolutely riddled with bugs. int instead of NSUInteger. <= instead of <. Heaven knows what that p is good for.

Comment: And you really need to learn how to write a clean specification for a method. Your code seems to count something. Why?

Answer (score 8):

```
NSMutableSet* set1 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array1];
NSMutableSet* set2 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array2];
[set1 intersectSet:set2]; //this will give you only the obejcts that are in both sets

NSArray* result = [set1 allObjects];
```

if result.count is greater than one it means array A have values that are in array B.

Comment: I love sets, they will change your life